# UIImagePickerController camera freezes when flash goes off on iPhone 4

Tags: camera, uiimagepickercontroller, ios4, led

Using the camera to capture an image ... everything works fine UNLESS the flash goes off (which is does automatically in low light situations).

Is anyone else seeing this?

What, if any, solutions are there to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Um, I think you meant to tag this as a camera flash issue rather than an Adobe Flash issue. I don't think us Flash people are going to be able to help you on this one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue and found a work around by removing and then reloading the picker:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
```

however it doesn't work if you have an overlay view (it places the camera view on top of the overlay in the view hierarchy) so I finally used the following setting for the picker

```
picker.cameraFlashMode =  UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
```

in order to block the camera flash...

Comment: I'm going to try this out in the next day or two to verify.  Btw, I think you meant "UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff" in your example code.  Thanks btw.